# Unbounded Operator in Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

I am trying to understand why the operator $S$ below is unbounded.

We have $X \subset Y$ two Hilbert spaces, $X$ dense in $Y$ with continuous inclusion. Then we define $D(S)$ as being the set of $u$ such that the antilinear form $v \mapsto (u,v)_X$, $v \in X$ is continuous in the topology induced by $Y$.

Then we define $S$ by putting $(Su,v)_y = (u,v)_X$.

Question: why is this $S$ necessarily unbounded?

Can somebody give me any hint about how to justify it?
I don't need a complete proof of the statement, I naturally want to do this by myself, I just need a hint...

Thank you very much people!

Comment: "Unbounded" is often used when "not necessarily bounded" would be more accurate.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case. Because I could not show that this is neither bounded or unbounded. But the book states that this is unbounded

Comment: I would look at the formal definition of *unbounded* in the book then. It is probably that $S$ is linear, and its domain $D(S)$ is a linear subspace of $X$. Note that a bounded operator defined on the whole space is an example of an unbounded operator.

Comment: What if $ X=Y=(\mathbb R,|\cdot|)$?